# GitFlow merge conflicts between release and develop

Tags: release-management, gitflow, merging, pull-requests

I've been using Git and GitFlow for quite a few years now, but this is still confusing me.

Let's say I open branch `release/1.1.1` to let the stakeholders test their application.

While they're testing devs complete 2 new features and merge them on `develop`.

Meanwhile stakeholders ask for 2 small fixes on `release/1.1.1`, devs fix them and push them directly on `release/1.1.1`.

Now they open a PR from `release/1.1.1` to `develop` so that the fixes are included in `develop` as well.

**THERE ARE MERGE CONFLICTS**

How can I fix those merge conflicts on the `release/1.1.1` branch without also including changes from `develop` or without overriding them instead?

My hypothesis are:

1. make `fix` branches form `release/1.1.1` too and make PR from there to `release/1.1.1` **and then** to `develop` this way merge conflicts will be handled in the fix branch instead of `release/1.1.1`
2. push fixes directly on `release/1.1.1` and then make a separate branch to handle the PR towards `develop` so that the merge conflicts will be handled there and not on `release/1.1.1` instead

In the picture below isn't really clear how to handle such merge conflicts, I feel my solutions will mess up my history.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is probably more consistent with GitFlow, but I've tended to use a variation on Option 2, but the variation comes from a need to have checks prior to merging into a controlled (release or `develop`) branch - I'd create a branch for the change, merge into the release branch, and then merge the release branch into develop, with an intermediary branch for resolving merge conflicts if any exist. Since this is usually an exceptional case, the intermediary branch is rarely needed. Your Option 2 could be better for your situation and is what I'd lean toward.

I would also point out that I've typically only seen release branches for major and minor versions. Patches would be additional commits into the release branch, without their own branch. I don't think this has any bearing on your current situation, but it could be something to consider. Instead of having a `release/1.1.1` branch, you would have a `release/1.1` branch and any `1.1.1` or `1.1.2` patches would be in that same branch.

Comment: Hey, thanks great answer! Just a clarification on your second point: so you don't version counting the new features / fixes on develop? You just add one minor for each `release` (unless it's not backwards compatible)?

Comment: @CarloMoretti I don't know what you mean by "version counting the new features/fixes on develop". There's only `main`, `develop`, and `release/x.y` branches that are long-lived. A patch release `x.y.z` is a tagged commit on `release/x.y` that will get merged into `main` and `develop`. Of course, you can also drop `main` and only use `develop` and release branches for some efficiency, but would move away from GitFlow.